# Property 'getMetadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflec

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to use the Reflect to get a template of my component by I get this error

```
   console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('annotations',SectionsTemplateComponent)[0].template);
```

knowing that I have reflect-metadata in my packege json

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346008/reflect-getmetadata-not-working-in-angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflect.getMetadata not working in angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346008/reflect-getmetadata-not-working-in-angular2)

Answer (score 26):

For me, adding `import 'reflect-metadata'` fixed the problem.

Comment: should be noted that vscode gets _confused_ at times: it doesn't update the typings. You should restart the IDE after importing `'reflect-metadata'`

Answer (score 15):

Check if you have done the following items:

1. install `reflect-metadata`:

```
// if you have npm as your package manager
npm install reflect-metadata

// if you have yarn as your package manager
yarn add reflect-metadata
```

2. put its package name in `types` array as a compiler option in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
   ...,
   "types": ["reflect-metadata"]
   ...
}
```

3. import it in your source file:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

These 3 will do the trick!

Comment: Well detailed and the best answer so far as the current version of TypeScript `^4.8.4`.

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install reflect-metadata -D

import 'reflect-metadata'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Do you include the library like below in your main HTML page:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script> <----
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```