# Reflect.getMetadata not working in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I used this `(Reflect.getMetadata('annotations',AppComponent)[0].template);` in plunker it works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/f47uORghJXaq0FtD00Th?p=preview

but in my project I have this error  `Property 'getMetadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'`

this is my configuration of project

packege.json

```
{
  "name": "ng2-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Angular2 playground for different ng2-* components",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akserg/ng2-demo"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akserg/ng2-demo/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "typings install",
    "play": "gulp play",
    "start": "npm run play"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/akserg/ng2-demo#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "dragula": "^3.7.1",
    "es6-promise": "~3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "~0.35.0",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.6.1",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.0.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "^1.6.5",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.1.10",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.0.3",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^1.2.3",
    "ng2-toasty": "^1.7.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.4.0",
    "del": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-gh-pages": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.8.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "serve-static": "^1.10.0",
    "typings": "^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

Systemjs.code.js

```
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'dist': 'dist', // 'dist',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'ng2-toasty': 'node_modules/ng2-toasty',
        'ng2-dnd': 'node_modules/ng2-dnd',
        'ng2-slim-loading-bar': 'node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar',
        'ng2-dragula': 'node_modules/ng2-dragula',
        'ng2-bs3-modal': 'node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal',
        'ng2-ckeditor': 'node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/',
        'ng2-uploader':'node_modules/ng2-uploader'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'dist': {main: 'boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'ng2-toasty': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'ng2-dnd': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'ng2-slim-loading-bar': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'ng2-ckeditor': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'ng2-dragula': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'ng2-bs3-modal': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'ng2-uploader': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade',
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        uiColor: '#990000'
    }

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ]
}
```

I'm still using angular2 rc2 but I dont know from where comes the error
and thanks for helping

[image]

Comment: update `"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2"` to `"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3"` and execute a `npm update`. What you are seeing is just a typing error in TypeScript

Comment: I changed the version to ^1.0.3 always same problem

Answer (score 4):

Add below line on top of your component-

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect-metadata.d.ts"/>"
```

Assuming you are using VScode.

See if this helps.

Comment: It works on RC4... I would suggest to upgrade it RC4 instead of using RC2

Comment: Just FYI... In plunker, you are using ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.4'

Answer (score 1):

Try to add [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js). It is a library with polyfills for ECMAScript 5, 6 and 7. Also install its typings. Add `"core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654"` to your `typings.json` and run `typings install`

Comment: I added it like this
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2",
    "node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#aee0039a2d6686ec78352125010ebb38a7a7d743",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after I interrupted the build process, then re-built it, even with the project running with "$ ionic serve" on another Cmder tab, that solved my problem.

Obs: build made with "$ ionic build android" command, using Ionic 2 CLI v2.1.18

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with Typescript.
As of now, other than install/update the 'reflect-metadata' package to resolve the error at build time, you should add in the **tsconfig.json** the library file *es2015.reflect*:

`"compilerOptions": {
        ...
        lib: [
            ...,
            "es2015.reflect",
            ...
        ]
        ...
    }`

to resolve the warning in the ide (tested on VSCode).

Comment: This only adds `Reflect` as global, but not the extension `Reflect.getMetadata`. There seems to be no TypeScript lib entry which augments `Reflect` that way.